# Externalizing property file and Application Context file - Spring XD custom module

Tags: spring-xd

Is there a way we can externalize the application-context and property files while deploying spring-xd custom module ? When i deploy the module, i just see the jar inside in xd/custom-modules/processor. However, The out of the box spring-xd modules has a folder structure like http-client/Config/httpconfig.xml and http-client/Config/httpclient.properties.

Answer (score 0):

At least for properties it is possible to place them in xd/config/modules/type-of-module/module-name/module-name.properties. I didn't try out application context files yet.

For more details see here: [XD docs: module configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#_module_configuration)